# How to format text file to be readable in terminal

Tags: terminal, less, text

I thought this would be an easy question to find an answer to online, alas not.

In a nut shell I want to be able to open a text file to be formatted to be nicely readable in the terminal.

Background: I use a programme called cheatsheet which I have a folder in my .config of cheatsheets I have made and I can then type 'cheat ' into my terminal emulator and then in my .bashrc file I have function which pipes the cheatsheet into 'fold' and then pipes it into 'less'.

The reason I pipe it into fold is that for whatever reason less doesn't wrap the text on the lines around, and instead truncates them.

Regardless, I have done my best inside the text files so that the spaces and tabs are tightly constrained. But when I view it in the terminal using cheat, or even cat (without using less) the lines are shifted seemingly randomly, some words have inexplicably large spaces between them.

So how can I perform formatting in the text file so I can create a 'what you see is what you get' situation when I open these files to be viewed in the terminal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `inexplicably large spaces between them`  ... that is when the text alignment is to both left and right margins ... microsoft calls the style "justified" ... the name in the linux realm may be different

Comment: What's the output of `file textfile.txt` ? Should be "Unicode text, UTF-8 text" in most cases. if not try to convert it with `iconv`

Comment: "less doesn't wrap the text on the lines around" ... did you try `less -S`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Yes, I'd already tried less -S. Although I just cat the document into less and it did wrap the text, so the issue must be with cheatsheet. Anyway, back to the problem: I like the iconv suggestion, but I think it was already UTF-8 because file said it was ASCII. I've converted it to a few things, such as UTF16 and back to UTF8, but every time it still has the strange spaces and alignment/margin in the terminal which it doesn't when viewed in Featherpad. Hmm